# An alternating sum involving a product of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

I encountered the sum below, where $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$, $c_{3}$, $c_{4}$ and $d$ are some given positive constants. Does anyone have an idea how to simplify it?

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{d} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}k}{c_{1}-k}\binom{c_{2}-2k}{c_{3}-k}\binom{c_{4}-k}{k}.
$$

Comment: Mathematica and Maple return the sum unevaluated, even with given values for the $c_i$'s. If it is not tractable for modern summation algorithms, this sum is likely unsimplifiable.

Comment: Mathematica does convert it into a "difference root" implicit function, which is probably not helpful.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Does it give something if we remove the 1/(c_1-k) part? I don't have a licence for Mathematica.

Comment: the only "closed-form" it gives is a difference root expression.

Comment: You can try something like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+%28-1%29%5Ek+*+k+%2F+%28c1+-+k%29+*+%281*binomial%28c2-2*k%2C+c3-k%29%29++*+%281+%2B+0*binomial%28c4+-+k%2C+k%29%29+for+k+from+1+to+infinity (and change the formula of the general term) on the wolfram alpha platform. (Computation time reduced.) Even if going to infinity with $d$, there is no "good guess". The last binomial factor is a problem when trying to get a hypergeometric form (in the presence of at least one of the other factors). In the link i used $1+0\cdot \binom{c_4-k}k$ to get an answer in the offered computer time